# GWT: How to retrive and modify HttpServeletResponse in RPC?

Tags: java, session, gwt, cookies

I am making a web app which uses RPC as the main communication mechanism between my client and server. One thing I want to do is to prevent a user opening my web app in multiple browser tabs. So I want to assign some tab id based on the login time.

Unfortunately, it is not as simple as I expected. First of all, I do not know how to set cookies from my rpc servelet (RemoteServiceServlet) to the client's browser. I am not sure whether it is doable. If not, I hope there is a way to pass the cookie to the client by modifying the HttpServeletResponse. (I do not want to mix this cookie with my returning data.) Furthermore, how can I get the Response object from client side?

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried to set some cookies in the HttpServletResponse which I got from calling getThreadLocalResponse() But I cannot get them from the client side. Cookies.getCookie(xxx) always returns null.

Comment: Did you check this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045431/sessions-and-cookies-to-autologin-in-gwt)? Especially this link: https://varuntayur.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/session-management-in-gwt/

Answer (score 1):

To access the `HttpServletResponse` from your `RemoteServiceServlet`, just call [`getThreadLocalResponse()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.html#getThreadLocalResponse()) (same is available for the request too).

Comment: Seems like the HttpServletResponse I got from calling getThreadLocalResponse() is not the same as the one returning to the client. I set some cookies in the HttpServletResponse, but I cannot get it from the client side. Cookies.getCookie(xxx) always returns null.