# Send Cookie on every request to identify user?

Tags: security, session, gwt, cookies

I'm not getting my head around the whole session-management thing.

I've now implemented [this](https://varuntayur.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/session-management-in-gwt/) to take care for the login process and also [this](https://code.google.com/p/xsrf-safe/) example to protect my services from XSRF attacks.

But now that I'm having it I wonder:

- If I turn on SSL, is the cookie sent **before** a secure connection is built up? So is this session ID (the cookie) ever secure?
- Is it save to send the cookie on each request to identify the user? E.g. if a user wants to view *his*/*her* settings, to make sure it's not a fake request that tries to retrieve the settings from another user. Is it clear what I mean by that? 
  I would send the session ID on each request, compare it to the session ID in my database and if the request-token (XSRF securiy) is fine I execute the request - or is that too much overhead?

I'm still not quite confident if what I'm doing here is 100% correct and I want to make sure that I don't unnecessarily break any security measures I've spent time implementing.

Answer (score 0):

SSL or TLS connections are established before the HTTP request is sent over the wire, so data in the request is encrypted.

I'm not sure I understand your second question, but a lot of web applications use cookie based authentication to identify the user. As cookies are automatically sent to the website, you have to protect yourself against [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks.

Comment: Okay, so one would each time receive the cookie from the client, look into the database e.g. `User client = getUserFromCookie(cookie);` and proceed with the request for *that* user, right? I do that for **every** request on the server side that I want to be "cookie-protected" if I got that now right?

Comment: That is one way of doing it. But since you are creating the cookie in the first place you could also encode all the info in the cookie, protect it with a MAC and skip the database lookup altogether.

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow you here. Sorry I don't have the mindset for this stuff yet. Could you elaborate how I can get rid of the database lookup?

Comment: Basically stuff all the things you need into the cookie (which travels back end forth between client and server). To ensure nobody can modify the cookie (either on the client or in transit), protect it with a Message Authentication Code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code